# C# to download document from google drive not saving correctly

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I am writing a simple program to download a document (.docx) from my google drive and save it as such. The problem is that when the file is saved, Microsoft word can not open it because it says it is corrupt. If anyone can think of why this does not work, I would very much appreciate the help as I am a bit stumped on this one.

The code:

```
    Uri link = new Uri(sharablelinkhere);
    DriveService service = new DriveService();
    var stream = service.HttpClient.GetStreamAsync(link);
    var result = stream.Result;
    using (var fileStream = File.Create("E:\\test.docx"))
    {
        result.CopyTo(fileStream);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I needed the correct export link and all worked fine.

```
https://docs.google.com/document/d/FILE_ID/export?format=doc
```